# Fabric Answers Event: how to view all values of a category attribute, not just the top 10

Tags: google-fabric

Using Fabric Answers events, is it possible to see all values of a category attribute instead of just the top 10?

See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYUdf.png) for how Fabric shows category attribute values. I am not seeing where I can view all values rather than just the top 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not currently possible to view values outside of the top 10. It's an enhancement that team's been thinking about and I'll make sure to pass along your feedback!

*Update*

You can now link your Fabric app to Firebase and view up to 25 attributes and get access to Big Query. Check out https://docs.fabric.io/apple/answers/ios-export-firebase.html for more details.

Comment: +1 for this enhancement request. Analytics where you can't actually see what your users have done unless it's in the top 10, is too limited to be that useful, unless I am missing something (which is possible). Here's a basic question that cannot be answered with this limitation in place: "is anyone using that new feature I just built?". Events recording that feature aren't going to be top 10, if it's a new feature...even just a csv dump of all events would be allow workarounds.

Comment: For this useful feature +1

Comment: Is there a way to track the progress of this feature implementation? This is definitely something that is key to me too.

Comment: Updated original answer with a new feature between Fabric and Firebase.

Comment: When will You update Google Analytics API which is used in Answers? The old API (you are using) is using .plist file to get data for analytics. If You have more configurations than one (most of us) and want to test both for analytics, you have to split configurations to targets and make each target to include different google plist file. Please update your Google Analytics API which in new one accept parameters to be passed programmatically which enables to use configurations instead of targets (bulky solution). Moving To pure GA just because of that...